# .NET Console.WriteLine Method ToString Behavior

Tags: .net, tostring

As I know .NET Console.WriteLine method calls ToString method of Class. In the below code Console.WriteLine(object) call and Console.WriteLine(object.ToString()) call produces different outputs. If override keyword is added to ToString method in the below code the outputs become same. But i wonder why the outputs are different in the first case.

Program Output:

TestOverrideConsole.Program    (Class Name)

Hello from Program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine(p);
        Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public String ToString()
    {
        return "Hello from Program";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to override ToString, otherwise you are just hiding the one from Object and your `ToString` is not called at `Console.WriteLine(p)`, only if you call it directly.

Comment: Recommended read: [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords)

Answer (score 0):

When you override a method, you're basically putting a new implementation into a "slot"<sup>1</sup> that's already been designated by your base class as being for that method. When you shadow a method (don't use override), you're taking a name that your base class used and assigning that name to a *different* "slot".

When the compiler is performing name/overload resolution, what it's basically trying to decide is which "slot" to route the method call through (because due to overloading, you may have multiple methods with the same names but they'll have different "slot"s).

When `Console.WriteLine` was compiled, the only slot the compiler could pick for `ToString` is the one that `Object` declared for *its* `ToString` method. So that's the only method it'll ever call<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm using "slot" here because, whilst you won't find it used in the C# Spec, so far as I recall, down at the CLR level, shadowing methods are marked with `newslot`.

<sup>2</sup>Not 100% sure it does literally call `ToString` itself, rather than going via any number of indirections, but it's good enough here to say that it does.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine(p)` calls `ToString` method of object as `ToString` method is not overridden.

```
public String ToString()
```

This method hides `ToString` method of base class and does not override it. That's the reason why outputs differ. To properly override `ToString` method you have to add the override keyword to the method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code so it compiles, you can [inspect it here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAIAYAEqCMBuAWAChjUBmbHANmwCZKB2Ygb2M3cptQBZMBZAIYBLKAApc6ANoBdTALABzAM4BKNh1ZEO2zADd5mAA6YAvJigBTAO6YACqJWEtO9rgCcow4/Uv3ngHQAKgD2AMrAYCIKDt7O7AC+xIkkRKj0tiw+2BThkVAKmCG5UQ5Zmi6uDJgARAASFgA2DcGYAGZgwQC2jNVO2snxQA=),

```
using System;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new P();
        Console.WriteLine(p);
        Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
    }
}

class P
{
    public String ToString()
    {
        return "Hello from Program";
    }
}
```

You'll observe that the compiler issues this warning

> warning CS0114: 'P.ToString()' hides inherited member
>   'object.ToString()'. To make the current member override that
>   implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new
>   keyword.

which I think is pretty self explanatory.

When `WriteLine()` calls `ToString()` it is accessing the virtual member, which you have not overridden.